# Postfix: Only accept mails from specific domains

Tags: postfix, whitelist

How can I configure postfix that it only accepts emails from specific domains?

I added entries to /etc/postfix/sender_access, e.g. "domain.xyz permit_auth_destination", did a postmap on the file and added the line

```
"smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access"
```

to main.cf

The whole smtpd_recipient_restrictions looks like this:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

p.s.: I know that mail addresses can be easily faked, but that's not the point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main.cf`

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unauth_destination,
  reject_non_fqdn_sender,
  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
  reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname,
  reject_unknown_client_hostname,
  check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/whitelist,
  reject
```

In `/etc/postfix/whitelist`

```
my.whitelisted.tld OK
```

Change `my.whitelisted.tld` to domain you want to allow.

then run `postmap /etc/postfix/whitelist` and `service postfix restart`

Comment: I kept  permit_auth_destination in the access file, because - as far as I know - OK *can* make your server an open relay if the sender fakes a domain from the list. However, thanks :)

Comment: @Steffen `reject_unauth_destination` should block such attempts in early rules, so it's Ok with `OK` :)

Comment: @Steffen BTW, it's better to use `reject_unauth_pipelining` in `smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining`